# Why GridView item don't wrap?

Tags: gridview, qml, qtquick2

I'm using a **GridView** in my qml code but it shows all the item in only one row but I don't want it. You can see in picture below:
[image: click to see picture]
and this is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

ApplicationWindow{
    id: a
    width: 480
    height: 640
    FolderListModel{
        id : listModel
        folder: "/home/muhammad/Pictures"
        nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]
    }
    Component{
        id: dd
        Image {
            id: m
            width: a.width/3
            height: width
            source: filePath
        }
    }

    GridView{
        verticalLayoutDirection: GridView.TopToBottom
        layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
        anchors.fill: parent
        flow: GridView.FlowLeftToRight
        model: listModel
        delegate: dd
    }

}
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of each cell in a `GridView` is determined by [`cellWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#cellWidth-prop) and [`cellHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#cellHeight-prop). The default cell size is 100x100. Notice that the cell size determines the layout of the view. Delegates can decide how to cover the area that is reserved for each cell. You may want to resize the `Image`-delegate to `cellWidth` and `cellHeight`, and set its `fillMode` to `Image.PreserveAspectFit`, for example.

```
GridView {
    id: gridView

    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 200

    delegate: Image {
        width: gridView.cellWidth
        height: gridView.cellHeight
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
}
```